# Number guessing game in Flask

Tags: python, python-2.7, flask

I keep getting the same issue with this code in flask.  I'm doing the number guessing game, 1-100, and it always responds with "Too Low" for some reason.

```
from flask import Flask, render_template, session, request, redirect 
import random 

app = Flask(__name__)
app.secret_key = 'thisIsSecret'

@app.route('/')
def index():
session['number'] = random.randrange(0,100)
print session['number']
return render_template("index.html")

@app.route('/guess', methods=['POST'])
def result():
if request.form['guess'] == session['number']:
    answer = "Correct"
    return render_template("index.html", answer=answer)
elif request.form['guess'] > session['number']:
    answer = "Too Low"
    return render_template("index.html", answer=answer)
else:
    answer = "Too High"
    return render_template("index.html", answer=answer)

app.run(debug=True)
```

And my HTML file looks like this...

```
<html>
<head>
   <title>Great Number Game</title>
   <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{{ url_for('static', filename='style.css') }}">
</head>
<body>
  <h1>Welcome to the Great Number Game!</h1>
  <h3>Think of a number 1 - 100...see if you can guess it right!</h3>
  <p class="answer">{{ answer }}</p>
  <form action='/guess' method='post'>
      Guess: <input type='text' name='guess'>
      <input type='submit' value='submit'>
  </form>
</body>
```

What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can see 2 things wrong with your code right now. First, your guessed number is coming in as a string. In order for it to be properly compared with the session's guess you should convert it into an integer, first: `int(request.form["guess"])`.

Second, it looks to me like the comparison operator for the "Too Low" check needs to be flipped. Right now, it's going to return "Too Low" when the guessed number is greater than the session's number. You probably want the opposite.

In conclusion, your first `elif` should look like this:

```
elif int(request.form['guess']) < session['number']:
    answer = "Too Low"
    return render_template("index.html", answer=answer)
```